# Gmail Divs- How fast do they change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

Currently developing an extension for Gmail that inserts a couple of buttons, using jquery.

I'm relying on the `canvas_frame`iframe and a couple of more `div` referrenced with their `class` names, not by their ids.

How reliable is this? How frequent does Gmail gets their class names changed?

As a side note, I thought of an small javascript file to be pulled from a server constantly, that refreshes `class` names in case Gmail changes them. I don't like this approach (to change the code) since, this is a security extension, and this will probably request more permissions to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is pretty much a hack, there is no guarantee when Google might change the underlying HTML structure.

This reminds me of [Remember The Milk for Gmail as Browser Add-on](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/gmail/addon/). They did the add-on not via Gmail API but by pretty much hacking the Gmail HTML. It breaks *really* frequently, due to Google "upgrading" Gmail.

To give you an idea how often Gmail is upgraded, take a look at the [list of Gmail versions](http://www.rememberthemilk.com/services/gmail/addon/status/) that RTM team is keeping track of. Gmail is basically updated every few days!

Kudos to the RTM engineers though, they usually fix their add-on to support the latest Gmail relatively quickly whenever it breaks.

That being said, in short, there is no telling how fast `<div id="canvas_frame">` might change, but at least now you have an idea how fast Gmail is changing.

Comment: Thanks bro. In short: to be reliable update frequently. Nevertheless, this can be thought as a security gap.